# How to completely remove Maven?

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, uninstallation

My instructor had us all install the Maven add-on for programming in Java. Now, any time I make a new Java program, it is not recognized by Eclipse. By this I mean it redirects to another program. Also, when looking in "Run Configurations", under "Java Applications", any new programs I make don't show up there. However, all programs should show up here.

### **Example:**

Say I have a program named "Test" that I made *before* installing Maven. Now say I made a program "Test2" *after* installing Maven. When running Test, it works fine. But when running Test2, it runs Test. Other than it showing in the directory on the left, Eclipse makes no indication that Test2 actually exists. That is my issue.

### **My Question:**

How do I *completely* remove Maven from my system? I don't want to use System Restore.

### **What I've Tried:**

I have removed the Environment Variable "M3 HOME" and removed it from the "Path" variable. The issue is still there, however.

I have a Windows 10 Lenovo Y50-70 Gaming Laptop (64 bit) with 4K resolution. I am using Eclipse Luna.

Comment: Can't you just uninstall it?

Comment: Maven is a simple ZIP that you unzip. So remove the install directory and you're pretty much done. But I don't understand the problem you were having with Eclipse...

Comment: I had to use several commands to add a bunch of crap to Eclipse's main files to add Maven. It doesn't show up in Programs and Features, and I wouldn't expect it to. It's made itself part of Eclipse. @resueman

Comment: You must also delte the directory .m2 from you user home directory

Comment: Not sure how to do that @Jens

Comment: @Spencer4134 Using the windows explorer?!

Comment: @Jens Where do I look? I have no idea where it is.

Comment: Google where is `.m2` directory...

Comment: Also, is there a way I need to improve this question to stop getting downvotes?

Comment: Yes, these lines in particular don't make any sense: "Since I did that, any class that I make isn't recognized by Eclipse." and "I cannot run any Java programs that I write. It just redirects to another program." You need to be more concrete. Give an exact example of what you mean. (And I haven't downvoted you.)

Comment: @DavidS I edited it. Also, I deleted that directory (Which was empty), but I still get a Maven option when right clicking the "src" folder in Eclipse

Comment: After your updates, this sounds even less like a Maven issue that before. Instead of going through Run Configurations what happens if you just right-click on the Project and choose "Run As > Java Application"?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/103888/discussion-between-spencer4134-and-davids).

Comment: Upvote for a good attitude if not the greatest question. Good luck with your studies.

Comment: newer eclipse version include the m2eclipse plugin which embeds maven directly into eclipse. but unless you add a pom.xml file to a project or the facet it should not matter if its around or not. You can create maven-less projects any time via the new project wizard. The project settings can also be changed any time if you should enable it by mistake.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After messing around a bit, I figured out the answer.

Right click any "src" folder, and click something along the lines of "Exclude Maven Artifact" under the "Maven" option. This removed it from Eclipse, and I can now make new programs and run them again.

Hope this helps whoever has my issue!